# Converting shortened URLs from different URL-shortening services back via Python

Tags: python, url, url-rewriting

I was wondering if there is a convenient way via an already available Python library to convert back shortened URLs into the 'native' URLs. For example, from a list of shortened URLs:

```
['some url from bitly', 'shortened url from twitter', ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://bit.ly/XXXX")
print r.url
```

`r.url` will be the resolved url as returned by the server the content resides on

Comment: I'd use `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)`, then use `r.headers['location']`. Otherwise, `requests` *follows* the redirect and makes two requests (at least).

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard library:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://shorturl')
response.geturl()
```